# Integer validation output

Tags: c

I've been learning C on my own and have been re-working a program out of the C Primer book. I was hoping a fresh set of eyes could possibly spot the one issue that I'm having.  As you can see by my output vs expected output I would like to get rid of the line "0 is a number". I believe a re-tooling of the while loop is the issue, but I can't seem to get rid of it despite the variations I've tried.

Output:

```
    Enter some integers. Enter 0 to end.
    1 two 3 0 4
    1 is a number.
    two is not an integer
    3 is a number.
    0 is a number.
```

Expected output:

```
    Enter some integers. Enter 0 to end.
    1 two 3 0 4
    1 is a number.
    two is not an integer
    3 is a number.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int get_int(void); //validate that input is an integer

int main(void)
{
    int integers;

    printf("Enter some integers. Enter 0 to end.\n");
    while (integers != 0)
    {
        integers = get_int();
        printf("%d is a number\n", integers);
    }
    return(0);

} // end main

int get_int(void)
{
    int input;
    char ch;

    while (scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
    {
        while (!isspace(ch = getchar()) )
            putchar(ch); //dispose of bad input
        printf(" is not an integer\n"); 
    }    
    return input;
 }// end get_int
```

Comment: Note that your loop as currently written is not guaranteed to execute at all.  It is possible that `integers` would contain 0 before the loop is executed.  Using uninitialized variables leads to bugs.  If you compile with optimization and warnings, GCC will report that (`gcc -O3 -Wall` should do it; I use `-Wextra` too routinely).  Incidentally, IIRC, on Solaris, the stack is mostly zeroed, so there'd be a fairly good chance that `integers` is zero on entry to the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is  move the call to `get_int` into the condition of the while loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    int integers;

    printf("Enter some integers. Enter 0 to end.\n");
    while ((integers = get_int()) != 0)
    {
        printf("%d is a number\n", integers);
    }
    return(0);

} // end main
```

The problem with your existing code is that between calling `get_int()` and printing the value, you're not checking to see if it's returned your sentinel of `0`.

The other option would be to add an `if (integers == 0) { break; }` condition in between,
but in my mind doing the assignment in the condition is cleaner.

Comment: I've been known to write this loop this way myself, but if the initial processing and condition are any more complicated than this, I think the internal "break" statement is clearer.  One case that comes up a lot is `for (;;) { c = getchar(); if (c == EOF || c == terminator) break; ... }` -- you *can* write that entirely inside a while condition but only by assigning-and-testing `c` on the left side of a `&&` and testing it again on the right, which is like to confuse people.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to suspect that you need to retool the `while` loop.  Did you try something like this?

```
 for (;;)
 {
     integers = get_int();
     if (integers == 0) break;
     printf("%d is a number\n", integers);
 }
```

Also, your `get_int` would be better written with `fgets` (or `getline` if available) and `strtol`.  `scanf` is seductively convenient but almost always more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: This is one of Knuth's 'loop-and-a-half' constructs, which you can find more about with a Google search on 'Knuth loop-and-a-half'.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to put your condition and assignment into the while-loop. Right now your code relies on `integer` being set in the loop, then loops again to check if it's zero.

```
while((integer = get_int()) != 0)
```

will let you check at the same time as assigning integer. Don't forget the parenthesis, or your integer value will be the result of `integer = (get_int != 0)`, because `!=` has higher priority than `=` in C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the core of your loop:

```
integers = get_int();
printf("%d is a number\n", integers);
```

No matter what `get_int()` returns, the `printf` line will be executed. That line needs a separate `if`:

```
integers = get_int();
if (integers != 0) printf("%d is a number\n", integers);
```

Comment: But repeating the loop condition in the body of the loop is ugly.  What you've done works, but it is ugly!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I had quite a think before I posted the answer. There are various ways of solving this problem: using break (as per Zack) - adds a line, adds a conditional, uses break (so harder to follow flow imho); add a conditional (as per me) ugly as you say from a code purist point of view but easy for someone learning the language to learn from or John Ledbetter's solution (ideal from the code purist point of view but puts a lot of functionality into one line which can be harder for a learner to grasp from). Caveat Emptor!

Comment: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts//papers/SIGCSE-1995/LoopExits.pdf makes a really compelling argument IMNSHO for the break-in-the-middle being easier to understand than any of the alternatives.

Comment: @Zack guess it's just me that find's `break` hard to follow - it always leaves me with a feeling of insecurity - break to where? But I guess that's just me :-) The good thing is to see all three answers up here - as an overall learning experience for the OP, it's ideal, I would think.